# special chars generated when using HTML::TreeBuilder & HTML::Element

Tags: html, perl

I've two questions:

- If I take out any text using text() or as_trimmed_text() function and want to push in some element then do I need to use HTML::Entities::encode_entities? :

  ```
  my $text=$node->as_trimmed_text();

  $a->push_content($text);  # Do I need to use encode_entities here?
  ```
- Secondly after processing and generating whole html document using as_HTML() it's sometimes generating some special characters for example: Â(`&Acirc;`) as an extra char when all I see is single space in Dreamweaver.

Comment: If you have two questions, it's generally better to ask two separate questions instead of combining them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two answers:

- Assuming that you want the content of `$a` to be the same as the content of `$node`, you do not need to `encode_entities` as `push_content` inserts the passed string as a text node rather than parsing it as markup. OTOH, if the content of `$node` is `<span>` (represented in HTML source as `&lt;span&gt;`) and you actually want `$a` to display `&lt;span&gt;` (represented in HTML source as `&amp;lt;span&amp;gt;`), you would call `encode_entities` on it.
- Chances are that your input text contains raw UTF-8 characters which the code is interpreting as Latin-1 or a similar encoding. The "single space" characters are actually U+00A0, non-breaking space, which is represented in UTF-8 by the two bytes 0xc2 0xa0, which when interpreted in Latin-1 are "Â" and non-breaking space.

Comment: With regard to your 2nd answer, could you pl tell me how to remove or handle those chars?

Comment: You could open the file with the `:utf8` input layer, to have perl convert the UTF-8 bytes to perl's internal representation. Or you could use the methods from the `Encode` module to decode the UTF-8 bytes in the same manner. Or to go the other way, if you're using a sufficiently new version of HTML::TreeBuilder (and HTML::Parser), you can use the `utf8_mode` method.